# In LaTeX how do I get a straight single apostrophe in A4 page when textcomp tramples the page size?

Tags: symbols, packages

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{textcomp} % trampled page size
\textquotesingle $\backslash$chi
```

I need to write a vertical quotation symbol as defined in textcomp but adding this package trashes my A4 pagesize.

Comment: please post a complete small document that shows the problem. The textcomp package has no effect on page size.

Comment: Before leveling accusations that a package "tramples" or "trashes" page size parameters, you should carefully verify that the accusation is correct.